# Which Java Collection is best suited to store and manipulate integer data from a table?

Tags: java, collections

I have to choose a Java Collection to store and manipulate data from a table. The table structure is: `Create table Team(team_id int primary key, Female int, Male int, Total int)`

So far I have used LinkedHashMap and I've got this:

```
    LinkedHashMap<Integer,Integer> male=new LinkedHashMap<Integer,Integer>();
        male.put(1,108);
        male.put(2,107);
        male.put(3,108);
        male.put(4,108);
        male.put(5,108);
        male.put(6,109);
        LinkedHashMap<Integer,Integer> female=new LinkedHashMap<Integer,Integer>();
        female.put(1,23);
        female.put(2,23);
        female.put(3,23);
        female.put(4,22);
        female.put(5,23);
        female.put(6,23);
        Set maleSet = male.entrySet();
        Set femaleSet=female.entrySet();
        Iterator miterator = maleSet.iterator();
        Iterator fIterator = femaleSet.iterator();
        Map.Entry me1 = (Map.Entry)miterator.next();
        Map.Entry me2 = (Map.Entry)fIterator.next();
        while(miterator.hasNext()&&fIterator.hasNext()){
        System.out.println(me1.getKey+"\t",me1.getValue+"\t"+me2.getValue+"\n");
}
```

Is this appropriate for this problem? I also need to add the values and store then in another LinkedHashMap set. How can I do that?

Comment: Depends on the problem you're trying to solve. Why do you want 2 lists? Wouldn't the typical single `List<RowItem>` be a better fit (`RowItem` can be a custom class of yours with methods like `int getFemale()`)?

Comment: I'm new at using collections so I haven't thought of using custom classes with collections. Thanks, I think I know how to go about this now.

Comment: Why not create Team object? You can store ArrayList or Map like that,  ArrayList<Team> team = new ArrayList<Team>();

Comment: Tried that. It's working now. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do you know google's tool jar: guava.
it has a Collection:Table

you can try it,or rewrite it.

```
Table<R,C,V> table = HashBasedTable<R,C,V>.create()
```